# 仮想環境のLinuxでsendmailコマンドを実行し、Gmailにテストメールを送りたいです

Tags: linux, virtualbox, sendmail

仮想環境のLinuxでsendmailコマンドを実行すると以下のメッセージが表示されます。

```
can't connect to remote host 127.0 0.1 Connection refused
```

sendmailコマンドを使ってパソコンの仮想環境からGmailなどのアカウントにメールを送ることはできるのでしょうか。

**実行コマンド:**

```
$ sendmail xxx@gmail.com
```

**実行環境*:*

・VirtualBoxでブリッジアダプタ＋ホストオンリーアダプタを設定している
・同一ネットワーク(自宅の無線LAN)に接続している他の端末へpingは通る
・ホストOSにpingが通らない

以上です。情報提供して頂けますと幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

mailコマンド+postfixを導入してGmailにメールを送る方法について記載します。

以下、Centos7.9+postfix+mailコマンドでメールを送るやり方

```
// postfixを入れる
# yum install postfix cyrus-sasl-plain

// 以下の設定をまるまる追記(+部分が追記)
# vim /etc/postfix/main.cf

+ relayhost = smtp.gmail.com:587
+
+ # SASL Authentication
+ smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
+ smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/gmail_passwd
+ smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
+ smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = plain
+ 
+ # TLS Settings
+ smtp_use_tls = yes
+ smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
+ tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
```

/etc/postfix/gmail_passwd にファイルを作成

```
smtp.gmail.com:587 アカウント@gmail.com:パスワード
```

パスワードを書いたファイルを適用・削除、postfix再起動

```
# postmap /etc/postfix/gmail_passwd
# rm -f /etc/postfix/gmail_passwd
# systemctl start postfix 
# systemctl status postfix
```

メール送信

```
# echo "本文" | mail -s "タイトル" -r xxxxxxxx@gmail.com xxxxxxxx@gmail.com
```

以下参考

- [Macでコマンドラインやプログラムからmailを送る](https://qiita.com/tmsanrinsha/items/75e06fbdd7e12409bb02)
- [[mailコマンド]Linuxからメールを送る](https://qiita.com/shuntaro_tamura/items/40a7d9b4400f31ec0923)